# AzureDevOps pipelines, buil results, code coverage, Why I can't download the code coverage results in a build result that is publicly available?

Tags: azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-artifacts

- I have enabled the code coverage in my build definition, which is
  available publicly.
- I can download the artifacts without being logged
  in since it's public account.
- But I can't download the code coverage
  without being logged-in?
- **Is there some setting I need to configure or something?**

Comment: The codecoverage is not part of the build-artifacts and is associated with the test-run that is created from this build (Go to "Test Plans" > "Runs", there is a record for the build with trx/codecoverage and detailed stats). i have not yet tried out public projects in AzureDevOps so i don't know if the test-runs are publicly available like the build is

Comment: Is there a way to make the test runs available, or do I need to publish it, and how cause based on the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops
I don't have to use publish task to publish it, but it doesn't work